# how to get input box values which is called by ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<form action="chngschdl.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <label class="home">Flight Name</label> <select name="select_catalog_query" ><?php echo $options1; ?></select>
    <br/><br/>
    <label class="home">Starting Route</label>  <input class="text" type="text" name="stroute" onKeyUp="numericFilter(this);" />    <label class="home">Deperture Time</label>  <input class="text" type="text" name="stdrt" /><br/>
    <label class="home">Ending Route</label>    <input class="text" type="text" name="enroute" onKeyUp="numericFilter(this);" />    <label class="home">Arrival Time</label>    <input class="text" type="text" name="enart" /><br/>
    <label class="home">Break Route Number</label>  <input class="text" type="number" name="bpn" maxlength='1' onkeyup="Bpoint(this.value)" /><br/>
    <label id='bp' > <?php //$i=$_SESSION['point'];$_SESSION['bp']=$broute[$i];?></label>   
        <button class="btn">Go</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

ajax getting data from:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( $_SESSION['type']!='admin')
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        return;
    }
    $point=$_GET['q'];
    $_SESSION['point']=$point;
    $bpoption="";
    for($i=0;$i<$point;$i++)
    {
        echo "<label>Break Route[$i]<label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class=text type=text name=broute[$i] />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo "<label>Arrival Time[$i]<label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class=text type=text name=bart[$i] />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo "<label>Departure Time[$i]<label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class=text type=text name=bdrt[$i] />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo "<br/><br/>";

    }

?>
```

i have to collect every data of Break Route, Arrival time and Departure time... how i suppose to get this data and use it in another page??      is there is other way around by not using ajax... bt it must be remembered that Break Route is not predefined...

Answer (score 0):

since your form fields are named like "name[$i]" it doesn't matter how many ajax-populated fields there are.

All you have to do on the page processing the form submit is:

```
foreach ($_POST["name"] as $name) {
  // do things
}
```